# In underscore/lodash, how to avoid duplicate calculation in a `map` method?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Here is my code:

```
var transformed = _(original).map(function (c) {
    return {
        lat: wgs2gcj(c.latitude, c.longitude).lat
        lng: wgs2gcj(c.latitude, c.longitude).lng
    }
});
```

Let's say `wgs2gcj` is a function from a third-party library and will take a long time to compute. Is there a way to do the calculation only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transformed = _(original).map(function (c) {
    var coordinates = wgs2gcj(c.latitude, c.longitude);

    return {
        lat: coordinates.lat
        lng: coordinates.lng
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps combined with [`_.memoize()`](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) in case duplicate entries do occur.

Answer (score 2):

For less code, you could use [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) as well:

```
_(original)
    .map(function(c) {
        return _.pick(wgs2gcj(c.latitude, c.longitude), 'lat', 'lng');
    })
    .value();
```